# How to get actual image from local path in PHP?

Tags: php, image, amazon-s3

*Disclaimer - Thanks for coming to this question! I would just like to say that I am an absolute beginner to PHP. Thanks!*

---

Hi! I am working on a project (more specifically, a mobile-only App), in which I need to do the following things -

- The user would give me his/her phone's path to the image, which is stored in his mobile.
- Through API, I would send the path to my website's PHP file, and the PHP would capture the image from the path.
- After displaying the image, the code would compress it with very high compression, and display the temporarily store the image.
- Then I would upload the image to AWS S3 media database(maybe with PHP SDK?), and obtain the image's link.

So that's my plan, is it possible to do? And what are the steps to do the 2nd & 3rd step - i.e. catching the image from the phone's local path, and compressing it?

Any help is appreciated :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For security reasons, you cannot capture the image from the phone's local path. You would need to upload the image from the phone to the server.

Comment: You cannot access anything on a remote device using PHP that would be a security risk.  You can upload using a form from the mobile device.

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard & 
@ SPlatten for the answer! Unfortunately, my development platform doesn't have the feature of uploading image files through API :( Anything that could save me? Also, does AWS S3 support uploading image from a local path? Thanks!

Comment: No, S3 does not support that either.

Comment: @kartik just ask the question about your platform. We may be able to help :)

Comment: Thanks @karol! My Platform is Thunkable (thunkable.com). We do not have the facility of sending actual images through API - that's the reason, I wanted to go with the local path thingy :) Thanks! P.S. If you want more info on my platform, please feel free to ask on our forum - communtiy.thunkable.com!

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility for you to remotely access any known mobile operating system's storage.

You want to upload a photo and process it - just do it! You can simply send the photo through your API to the PHP server, and it would receive it as it would receive any other file, e.g. from a website form.

Then, you use some tool like `Imagick` to edit the photo.

You return thumbnail to the user within the response of your API.

Yet simpler, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks @karol for the answer! So, it's clear that anyone cannot access image from a local URL. Does AWS S3 support image uploading through a local path? Thanks!